# How can I get "Always on when USB connected" back on Samsung Vibrant (Android Froyo 2.2)?

Tags: usb, screen, 2.2-froyo

How can I get "Always on when USB connected" display feature on Samsung Vibrant running Android Froyo 2.2? I used to love it on 2.1 Eclair but when I upgraded to 2.2 it is gone. Any trick to get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found some app on Market that sets this global setting ('[StayAwake](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji&feature=search_result)'). Missing setting looks like Samsung or TMO customization. I'm running official TMO 2.2 update (T959UVKA6) installed via miniKies

Comment: What app did you find?

Comment: @AlexMSU: If you associate your AndroidSE and Stack Overflow accounts, you should recover ownership of this question.

Comment: @Al Everett: thanks
@Matthew Read: 'StayAwake' but I think that should be part of standard settings. Is this Samsung or TMO customization?

Comment: @AlexMSU: Please update your answer with that information and, when you can, accept it as the answer.

Comment: Link to the StayAwake application: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji&feature=search_result . Seems to work on my Galaxy S

Answer (score 1):

If it is not in that menu it is probably no longer supported by default. You could likely achieve the same effect with either Tasker or Android scripting environment though.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to developing, though...

Homescreen>Menu button>Settings>Applications>Development>Stay awake

That's what it is like for AOSP phones, not sure about the vibrant.

Comment: Under 'Development' I see only 'USB debugging' and 'Allow mock locations'

Comment: I have this option on my 2.2 Vibrant.  Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: @Matthew Read, are you using T959UVKA6 or something else?

Comment: @somehume Modded KB1 (Bionix).  Pretty sure it's been the same on all the 2.2 builds I've had though.