# Where is "Stay Awake" option in Ice Cream Sandwich on the Galaxy S3?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, settings, charging, screen

I just upgraded to the Samsung Galaxy S III (Ice Cream Sandwich) from the Motorola Droid Bionic (Gingerbread).  On my Bionic, there was a "Stay Awake" check box that made it so my "Screen will never sleep while charging" under Settings->Applications->Development.

I can't find that checkbox on my S3.

Where is that setting in ICS and/or is there another way to keep my screen from turning off in ICS?

Thanks.

Comment: It must be a SGS3 thing. On my Galaxy Nexus I find it under `Settings | Developer options | Stay awake`.

Comment: Related questions: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13342 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12912 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6158 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23622

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I use widgetsoid and add a toggle widget to either the pull down menu or my home screen to toggle "stay awake" settings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Samsung removed "Stay Awake" from TouchWiz back in the first OTA for the Galaxy S1. Other ROMs like CyanogenMod still have it, and other AOSP based ROMs as well.

Be very careful using any kind of "Stay Awake" options with these devices that have the Super AMOLED screens. I used to use it when developing and testing the apps. I now have a "burn" in the screen from the time and the top bar.

Comment: Burn-in is not such a big risk as with older versions of Android since the Holo theme is darker than the previous ones. But a good point.

Comment: unless it is 100% black, anything that is on the screen in the "same state" can burn in.

Answer (score 9):

At least in vanilla ICS it's in `Settings` -> `Developer options` -> `Stay awake`, correct me if it's not there in GSIII.

If it's not there, you can try a couple of apps that can do this, at least on older Galaxy series phones.

[StayAwake](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji)

[Stay Awake Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.leppoc.android.dashboard)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It was good, but not as good as the "you really don't want to do that" answer from Ryan.

Answer (score 2):

My (non-rooted, stock) SGS3 has just been updated OTA to Jelly Bean 4.1.2, and the "Stay awake" option **is now present** under Developer options (second item, after "Desktop backup password" - the order of options has changed, I think).

Technically not an answer, because the question says "in ICS", but ... upgrade to JB!

(I haven't installed StayAwake or any such app, so this must have come from Samsung, so I assume they are OK with the risk of display burn-in.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "Developer options" menu under Settings? 
If not, you may have to enable it. 
Go to Settings > 
About phone and quickly touch several times (about 10 times) on "Build number". 
You'll see a toast saying "You're a developer now". 
Then you'll find the stay awake option under "Developer options".