# Why does my screen still turn off while charging?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “Stay Awake” option in Ice Cream Sandwich on the Galaxy S3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/where-is-stay-awake-option-in-ice-cream-sandwich-on-the-galaxy-s3)

I used to have an HTC Evo Shift. If I plugged it into a power cord, the screen would stay on until I explicitly pushed the power button. Now, I have a Samsung Galaxy S III. The screen turns off after a certain timeout regardless of whether it is plugged in. There is an option to change the timeout, but I would rather not be switching it all the time based on whether I have it plugged in. Is there an option I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock Samsung devices with TouchWiz (Samsung's version of Android) do not have this option to Stay Awake, and it is a good thing they don't. especially when they use the Super AMOLED screens. The image can burn in to the screen very quickly.